# How to make enemies in Game maker?

Tags: game-mechanics

how do i make enemies in game maker? its kinda hard since the enemies are falling from the sky I want the cats with the bombs to do more damage than the regular ones [image: Gameplay of my video game]

Comment: From previous comments on some of your closed questions, I can see that you have decided not to look at the initial GameMaker tutorials, due to the fact that parts of them conflict with the way in which you are intending to make your game. If you have the time, I would suggest a quick look at them, anyway. Some of them discuss concepts that you can still apply to your own process, and they would still impart knowledge that could be greatly beneficial to your intent. You would be surprised how much help certain tutorials can end up being, despite the subject being completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

An enemy is just an object whose actions -or interaction with- may lead to a *game over*. For enemies to work here, you need a *lose condition* and a way to enforce the lose condition. There is no other concept for *enemy* you need right now. The way you will implement the enemy is by dealing damage to the player upon collision.

You must create:

1. A parent object which you will call `obj_base_cat`. It will have no sprite. Declare a create behavior setting something like `vspeed = 5; damage = 0;`. The damage variable is just to have it as defined.
2. A player object.
3. A child object of `obj_base_cat`, with the regular cat sprite. When creating, invoke `super` (the parent behavior), and also `damage = 3;`.
4. A child object of `obj_base_cat`, with the bomb-having cat sprite. When creating, invoke `super` (the parent behavior), and also `damage = 3;`.
5. The player, when receiving the collision of an `obj_base_cat` (children will trigger this condition as well!) will be hit given the `.damage` property of the cat. Then you must handle the criterion for damage reception, life loss, and eventual game over. If you don't do that beforehand, the whole concept of enemy is meaningless.

Comment: I know i may be sounding like a stupid person, but, what does super mean

Comment: Sorry. I think it is called PARENT BEHAVIOR or INHERITED BEHAVIOR or something like that in GMS. If you can wait I can turn the pc and search. Try the terms I uppercased, in google (also add gamemaker studio in the search)

Comment: thanks! maybe i could just send you the .gmx file through email?